# create the service bus of azure using asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

We just wanted to create the service bus of azure using asp.net MVC web application.

We have to use the below line of code to create the azure service bus.

```
var credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromDevice("ClientId","ClientSecret",
    "tenantId",AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);

var azure = Azure.Configure().WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.Basic)
    .Authenticate(credentials).WithDefaultSubscription();
```

But we are getting the below error. Can you please help me with this.

Error = ClientSecret invalid.

Is there any way to create azure service bus from asp.net MVC So please suggest
Thanks in advance.

Comment: sounds like your client secret is not valid. Not much we can tell you about that, other than to make sure you check the documentation, and ensure you use a valid one. There's nothing in your which would be able to tell us anything about _why_ it's invalid (e.g. there's nothing to show you might have included it in your request incorrectly or anything).

Comment: Are you passing the correct value of Client Secret?

Comment: Yes. I'm passing the correct value. Give me a favor that Is there any other approach to create azure service bus namespace from asp.net MVC?

Comment: "I'm passing the correct value"...well Azure doesn't think so. I doubt that it's lying. You need to debug your code and double-check exactly what is being sent in reality. No matter what specific approach you use, you're not going to be able to tell Azure to do anything at all if you don't provide the correct credentials.